# How to find out if an Website is embedded with iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm programming a Website and i just don't know how to find out *using Javascript* if an Website is embedded with iFrame. I want to embed it into another site with iFrame but the styles **and** the content *should be different*. This means: If the page **is** embedded, then I want something else to be displayed than if it **is not** embedded 
Thanks, Daniel

Comment: when in an iframe - `window !== window.top`

Comment: if (window !== window.top) {
  /* my code if not embedded? */
}

Comment: no .. I answered the title "How to find out if an Website is embedded in an iframe" ... i.e. if in an iframe `window !== window.top` ... if not in an iframe `window === window.top`